# JPA Criteria Retrieving Item and Count

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to use the JPA Criteria API to return a summary from data in the format

"Distinct Value" -> Count of Distinct Value

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
    Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

    // this is where I want to get a count of the user levels and how many users per level
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
        root.get(User_.userLevel),
        // user count?
    ));
```

I prefer to do this via the criteria API.

Can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> tupleQuery = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<User> root = tupleQuery.from( User.class );

tupleQuery
  .select( cb.tuple( root.get( User_.userLevel ), cb.distinctCount( root ) ) )
  .groupBy( root.get( User_.userLevel ) );

List<Tuple> results = entityManager.createQuery( tupleQuery ).getResultList();
```

Comment: Cool example for aligning roots in a tuple query!